# Allowed free vector field theory Lagrangians

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, vector-fields

My understanding is that when constructing Lagrangians in QFT, one generally assumes that one can see ~more or less any term that is Lorentz invariant. As such, my question is: suppose one has a vector field $v_\mu$. What physical reason is there to not have Lagrangians of the form $\mathcal{L} \sim (\partial_\mu v_\nu)(\partial^\mu v^\nu)$ or $\mathcal{L} \sim (\partial_\mu v_\nu)(\partial^\nu v^\mu)$ since these terms are putatively Lorentz-invariant?

Comment: See my paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078.